# Why is dividing by double still 0, when all of the numbers are either decimal or double?

Tags: c#, double, division, zero

I am working on a test trading bot that connects to a centralized exchange. right now it is not actually trading but i wanted to simulate trading my making transactions fire when the price of an index goes above or below a set percent, then shift the profits into another index, while maintaining initial investment to rebuy the first index.

here is the code:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Kucoin.Net;
using Kucoin.Net.Clients;
using Kucoin.Net.Objects;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace BotTest
{
    class TokenHandler
    {
        private string tokenName { get; set; }
        private string tokenTicker { get; set; }
        private double tokenPrice { get; set; }
        private double tokenAmount { get; set; }
        private double tokenPreviousPrice { get; set; }
        private double totalValueUSDT { get; set; }

        public TokenHandler(string name, string ticker, double price, double amount)
        {
            this.tokenName = name;
            this.tokenTicker = ticker;
            this.tokenPrice = price;
            this.tokenAmount = amount;
            this.tokenPreviousPrice = price;
            this.totalValueUSDT = 0D;
        }
        public string getTokenName() => tokenName;
        public string getTokenTicker() => tokenTicker;
        public double getTokenPrice() => tokenPrice;
        public double getTokenAmount() => tokenAmount;
        public double getTokenPreviousPrice() => tokenPreviousPrice;

        public double getTotalValueUSDT() => totalValueUSDT;

        public void setTokenPrice(double value) => tokenPrice = value;

        public void setTokenPreviousPrice(double value) => tokenPreviousPrice = value;
        public void chnageTokenQuantity(double value, bool operation)
        {
            if (operation)
            {
                tokenAmount += value;
            }
            else tokenAmount -= value;

            totalValueUSDT = Math.Round((tokenAmount * tokenPrice), 2);
        }
        public void setTokenQuantityToZero() => tokenAmount = 0D;
    }
    
    class BotTest
    {
        //base buy/sell text
        public static readonly string kcBuyingTokens = "Buying {0} {1} for ${2}";
        public static readonly string kcSellingTokens = "Selling {0} {1} for ${2}";
        public static readonly string kcTotalProfits = "Total Earned: ${0} ({1} {2} [${3}] / {4} {5} [${6}] / {7} {8} [${9}]";
        public static readonly string kcTokenPrices = "{0} [${1}] / {2} [${3}] / {4} [${5}]";

        //error codes
        public static readonly string kcErrorApiTickerFetchFailure = "0x0001: Failed to fetch ticker data for {0}. Please retry later.";

        //kucoin api handler using rest api
        private static  KucoinClient kclient { get; set; }

        //Kucoin Api Accessor Information
        private static readonly string KC_API_KEY = "###################";
        private static readonly string KC_API_SECRET = "#####################################;
        private static readonly string KC_API_PASSWORD = "#################################";

        //start with just two entries for now
        public static TokenHandler kcHandlerMainTradeObject;
        public static TokenHandler kcHandlerMainStoreObject;
        //create one for storing USDT Value
        public static TokenHandler kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject;

        //check if traded
        public static bool tradeConducted { get; set; }

        //check if out of money
        public static bool outOfMoney { get; set; }

        //min and max changes before buy sell and hold.
        public static readonly double KC_MAX_INCREASE_BEFORE_HOLD = 0.000005D;
        public static readonly double KC_MAX_INCREASE_BEFORE_SELL = 0.000001D;
        public static readonly double KC_MAX_DECREASE_BEFORE_HOLD = 0.000005D;
        public static readonly double KC_MAX_DECREASE_BEFORE_BUY = 0.000001D;

        //starting value
        public static readonly double KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE = 100.00D;

        //min before we can buy the store
        public static readonly double KC_MIN_BEFORE_BUY_STORE = 5.00D;

        //print in color
        private static void printInColor(string value, ConsoleColor fg, ConsoleColor bg)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = fg;
            Console.BackgroundColor = bg;
            Console.Write(value);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }

        //setup the main KucoinClient
        private static void setupKucoinTradingClient()
        {
            kclient = new KucoinClient(new KucoinClientOptions()
            {
                ApiCredentials = new KucoinApiCredentials(KC_API_KEY, KC_API_SECRET, KC_API_PASSWORD),
                LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace

            });
            return;
        }

        //get and update the mainTradeObject
        private static  async Task<bool> updateTradeObject(int selector)
        {
            switch (selector)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var storedInfo = await kclient.SpotApi.ExchangeData.GetTickerAsync(kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenTicker());
                            if (storedInfo == null || storedInfo.Data.LastPrice <= 0.00M)
                            {
                                throw new Exception();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPreviousPrice() == 0.00D)
                                {
                                    //Assume this is the first time run and set defaults
                                    kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenPrice((double)storedInfo.Data.LastPrice);
                                    kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenPreviousPrice((double)storedInfo.Data.LastPrice);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Assume we already have a price in the stored data to check against
                                    kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenPrice((double)storedInfo.Data.LastPrice);
                                }

                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            printInColor("ERROR", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Black);
                            Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcErrorApiTickerFetchFailure, kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenTicker()));
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                case 1:
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var storedInfo = await kclient.SpotApi.ExchangeData.GetTickerAsync(kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenTicker());
                            if (storedInfo == null || storedInfo.Data.LastPrice <= 0.00M)
                            {
                                throw new Exception();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPreviousPrice() == 0D)
                                {
                                    //Assume this is the first time run and set defaults
                                    kcHandlerMainStoreObject.setTokenPrice((double)storedInfo.Data.LastPrice);
                                    kcHandlerMainStoreObject.setTokenPreviousPrice((double)storedInfo.Data.LastPrice);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Assume we already have a price in the stored data to check against
                                    kcHandlerMainStoreObject.setTokenPrice((double)storedInfo.Data.LastPrice);
                                }

                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            printInColor("ERROR", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Black);
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(kcErrorApiTickerFetchFailure, kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenTicker()));
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
            }
        }

        public static bool checkIfOutOFmoney() => kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenAmount() <= 0D && kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenAmount() <= 0D &&
            kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount() <= 0;

        public static async Task<bool> determineIfBuyOrSell()
        {
            //get the new trade value. Add more items later
            bool result = await updateTradeObject(0);
            bool storResult = await updateTradeObject(1);
            if (result)
            {
                //check if the trade object has the same price for previous and new, and if so
                //assume first buy and then buy Main Trad Object based on amount.
                if(kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice() == kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice() && kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount() > 0D)
                {
                    kcHandlerMainTradeObject.chnageTokenQuantity(Math.Round(kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount() / kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice(),8), true);
                    printInColor("BUY", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                    Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcBuyingTokens, new object[]{kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenAmount(),
                    kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount()}));
                    kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.chnageTokenQuantity(kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount(), false);
                    tradeConducted = true;
                }
                //check here if the price is different
                else
                {
                    //This line constantly returns ZERO even if the numbers are cast to double.
                    double percentDifference = (double)kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPreviousPrice() / (double)kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice();
                    if (percentDifference > (1.00D + KC_MAX_INCREASE_BEFORE_HOLD))
                    {
                        //set trade conducted to false
                        tradeConducted = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(percentDifference > (1.00D + KC_MAX_INCREASE_BEFORE_SELL))
                    {
                        if(kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenAmount() > 0.00D)
                        {
                            double totalProfitsThisTransction = kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice() * kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenAmount();
                            
                            double profitsToChange = totalProfitsThisTransction - KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE;

                            //check if we hit min
                            if(profitsToChange >= KC_MIN_BEFORE_BUY_STORE)
                            {
                                //set the store value
                                double totalStoreBought = Math.Round(profitsToChange / kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenPrice(),8);
                                kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.chnageTokenQuantity(KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE, true);
                                kcHandlerMainStoreObject.chnageTokenQuantity(totalStoreBought, true);
                                kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenPreviousPrice(kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenPrice());
                                printInColor("SELL", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                                Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcSellingTokens, new object[]{kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenAmount(),
                                kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenName(), totalProfitsThisTransction}));
                                printInColor("BUY", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                                Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcBuyingTokens, new object[] { KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE, "USDT", KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE }));
                                printInColor("BUY", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                                Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcBuyingTokens, new object[]{totalStoreBought,
                                    kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenName(),profitsToChange }));
                                kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenQuantityToZero();
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.chnageTokenQuantity(totalProfitsThisTransction, true);
                                kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenQuantityToZero();
                            }
                            tradeConducted = true;
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //set trade conducted to false as there is no main object to sell
                            tradeConducted = false;
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                    else if(percentDifference < (1.00D - KC_MAX_DECREASE_BEFORE_BUY) && percentDifference > (1.00D-KC_MAX_DECREASE_BEFORE_HOLD))
                    {
                        //we just need to buy, but check if USD is 0
                        if(kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount() > 0.00D)
                        {
                            kcHandlerMainTradeObject.setTokenPreviousPrice(kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenPrice());
                            kcHandlerMainTradeObject.chnageTokenQuantity(Math.Round(KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE/kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice(),8), true);
                            printInColor("BUY", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                            Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcBuyingTokens, new object[]{kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenAmount(),
                                kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount()}));
                            kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.setTokenQuantityToZero();
                            tradeConducted = true;
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //check if out of monmey
                            if(!checkIfOutOFmoney())
                            {
                                //set trade conducted to false as there is no main object to buy
                                tradeConducted = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                outOfMoney = true;
                                tradeConducted = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //set trade conducted to false as there is no main object to buy or sell
                        tradeConducted = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        //update USDT value
        private void updateKCUSDTStoreObject(double amount) => kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.chnageTokenQuantity(amount, true);

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            kcHandlerMainTradeObject = new TokenHandler("BTC", "BTC-USDT", 0.00000000D, 0.00D);
            kcHandlerMainStoreObject = new TokenHandler("MATIC", "MATIC-USDT", 0.00000000D, 0.00D);
            kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject = new TokenHandler("USDT", "USDT", 1.00D, KC_TOTAL_STARTING_VALUE);

            setupKucoinTradingClient();

            double currentValue = 0.00D;

            //setup handlers for checking if we traded or if we are outr of money
            outOfMoney = false;
            tradeConducted = false;

            while (!outOfMoney)
            {
                if (!tradeConducted)
                {
                    //we need to sleep here to prevent limiting. set to 1 sec.
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                await determineIfBuyOrSell();
                currentValue = kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTotalValueUSDT() + kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTotalValueUSDT() +
                    kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTotalValueUSDT();

                printInColor("INFO", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                Console.WriteLine(": " + string.Format(kcTotalProfits, new object[] {currentValue,kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenAmount(),
                kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTotalValueUSDT(), kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenAmount(),
                kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTotalValueUSDT(), kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenAmount(),
                kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerUSDTStoreObject.getTotalValueUSDT()}));

                printInColor("INFO", ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Black);
                Console.WriteLine(": Prices - " + string.Format(kcTokenPrices, new object[] { kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice(),
                    kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenName(), kcHandlerMainStoreObject.getTokenPrice(), "USDT", 1.00D }));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The API itself returns decimal data which is converted to Double. None of the numbers in the program are int, besides what is using in the sleep calls.

For some reason, even though the data here is already double, AND they are being cast to DOUBLE, it still returns 0.

```
//This line constantly returns ZERO even if the numbers are cast to double.
                   
 double percentDifference = (double)kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPreviousPrice() / (double)kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice();
```

and for example, a sample of the output in Step-Through. In this example, the price of both tokens is the same so should be equal to 1.00D, but it still returns 0.

[image]

Why is the above operation returning zero, even though they are already doubles, and the doubles were re-cast to double, just to ensure they were double? I have checked other relevant question here but none of my data is an integer / long type so i have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Tried to Divide 2 doubles and store them in a double but the value is returning zero

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange the cast shouldn't be necessary when looking at your debug window.

Can you assign  kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPreviousPrice() to a variable
and kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice() as well. and put a break point on the division line and see if you have values there?
Another way to do it would be to check the values on the debugger before the division happenned?

I cold be wrong but what I am thinking maybe the calls could be asynchronous and could be the reason you are having issues.

Comment: the class calls to get the stored data are not Asynchronous, but the calls to fetch the data from the API are, which happen before we even get to this point, and within another function, updateTradeObject. I encapsulated those calls into a Task.WaitAll Method to try and force the program to wait for all async calls to return, as well as separating the data into new variables, but the division is still returning 0, even if the numbers are the same.

Comment: Do you mean the two variables had a value different from 0 or infinity when breaking after the division line? I never heard of something like that before without threading or tasks being involved, but if you already have values for the 2 variables I don't understand. You can also play with a C# compiler online to double check. Can you add the following : Console.WriteLine("Token previous price: " + kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPreviousPrice());
Console.WriteLine("Token current price: " + kcHandlerMainTradeObject.getTokenPrice());

Comment: Unrelated but if I may, you should remove setTokenPreviousPrice and handle the logic inside setTokenPrice, unless you have some requirements to use that method.